# PHP Curl CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS with encoding

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to pass value in curl ... here is my code

```
$POSTVARS = array('u'=>'this&q=love', 'v' => 'hate');
$ch = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST      ,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    ,$POSTVARS);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER      ,0);  // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);  // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookiefile.txt");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookiefile.txt");
 $Rec_Data = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
```

Problem is CURL is taking 'this&q=love' as 2 values ...
I cannot encode this value (http_build_query or urlecode), i have to pass this value with '&' in it.

How can i do that

Thx

**EDIT**

I am trying to post google url to a proxy site

```
function proxy_browse($url,$POSTVARS){
 $ch = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST      ,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    ,$POSTVARS);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER      ,0);  // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);  // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookiefile.txt");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookiefile.txt");
 $Rec_Data = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 return $Rec_Data;
}

$keyword = 'u=google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=love';

$url = 'http://hostfast.info/includes/process.php?action=update';

$proxy_browse = proxy_browse($url, $keyword);
```

Here is the full code

Comment: Why cannot encode the value and just decode on the other side?

Comment: `http_build_query()` should do exactly what you want, just pass your `$POSTVARS` array to it. It will encode the `&` in the value string appropriately. `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` will accept a query string as input.

Comment: As i mention i can't encode value .... by encoding & into %26 it will change full value and output will come blank. ;(

Comment: If `this&q=love` is not two params than use `this&amp;q=love` or use htmlentities() on the string

Comment: @LozCherone &amp; also have & in it and CURL will not pass it ... so does htmlentities() ... it doesnot work ;(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [http_build_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) it will encode the values as expected, also google is expecting GET not POST, A simple test proves it

```
<?php 
function proxy_browse($url, $POSTVARS = array()){
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    if(!empty($POSTVARS)){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST ,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($POSTVARS));
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);  // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);  // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookiefile.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookiefile.txt");
    $Rec_Data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $Rec_Data;
}

//Wrong way, google expects a GET request
$url = 'http://google.com/complete/search';
$proxy_browse = proxy_browse($url,array('output'=>'toolbar','q'=>'love'));
//Error 405 (Method Not Allowed)!!
echo '<pre>'.htmlentities($proxy_browse).'</pre>';


//Working way
$url = 'http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=love';
$proxy_browse = proxy_browse($url);

/*
<?xml version="1.0"?><toplevel><CompleteSuggestion><suggestion data="love quotes"/></Com ...\snip*/
echo '<pre>'.htmlentities($proxy_browse).'</pre>';
```

Also you still need to use `http://`, if you are ever expecting `https://` schema then you should also add the following options to the curl request.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

good luck

### 2nd Edit

This seems to work, basically the `u` is the param the url following is the string, thats why http_build_query failed, my-bad i got abit confused with the double proxy idea ;p:

```
function proxy_browse($url, $POSTVARS = array()){
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    if(!empty($POSTVARS)){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($POSTVARS));
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookiefile.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookiefile.txt");
    $Rec_Data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $Rec_Data;
}

$keyword = array('u'=>'google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=love');

$url = 'http://hostfast.info/includes/process.php?action=update';

$proxy_browse = proxy_browse($url, $keyword);

echo '<pre>'.htmlentities($proxy_browse).'</pre>';
```

Comment: i am trying to pass a url there 'google.com/search?q=love&num=20' and if u use http_build_query it change the url and output comes blank ... so i cant use http_build_query any other way i can pass this url in ...thx

Comment: @Harinder check my 2nd edit(at bottom) i think it good togo ;p

Comment: np glad to help, i got abit confused ;-s

Answer (score 3):

```
$arr = array('u' => 'this&q=love', 'v' => 'hate');
$query = http_build_query($arr); // produces: u=this%26q%3Dlove&v=hate

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    , $query);
```

If you pass an array to curl, it'll basically do this exact sequence itself anyways.

Comment: Hi actually i am trying to pass a url there 'google.com/search?q=love&num=20' and if u use http_build_query it change the url and output comes blank ... so i cant use http_build_query any other way i can pass this url in ...thx

Comment: Pass this url HOW? To WHAT? Encoding the & and = to %26 and %3D is how you have to pass around url metacharacters that SHOULDN'T be treated as metachars at the receiving end.

Comment: Still doesn't explain what the problem is. The receiving end would decode `u=this%26q%3Dlove` as `key=u, val=this&q=love`, because what's what happens to encoded url metachars.

Comment: but if i encode 'u=google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=love' it will change google url and proxy site wont take it as url and it will not work ;(

Comment: also google is expecting GET not POST, ive just tested it with curl and its returning some XML successfully

Comment: thx for helping ... if you can run this code on your local host you will understand the problem i am facing .... when i run this code proxy site give me   400 Bad Request (?). as its not passing full url its just taking 'http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar' and leaving '&q=love' ...

Comment: @Harinder yeah just got a redirect to your proxy site, with a bad request message, use `curl_error($ch)` it will tell you that google is expecting GET.

Comment: @LozCherone is you check that its not passing full url.. its just taking 'google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar'; and leaving '&q=love' which lead to redirect to proxy site again